# Which events should I use for spawning a child process to ensure I always make a callback

Tags: node.js, eventemitter

I'm using node to wrap an executable and I'm using the spawn event emitter.  See the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) here. There are multiple events to subsribe to.

```
child = spawn("path/to/exe", args)
child.on('close', exitNormally )
child.on('exit', exitNormally )
child.on('error', exitAbnormally )
child.on('disconnect', exitAbnormally )
```

Should I be subscribing to all of them or is subscribing to `close` and `error` enough?  I have a callback that I have to execute regardless of whether the outcome is a success or not.  The docs for the events are [here](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_exit) but it doesn't seem to say explictly say what I'm asking and I want to confirm that my thinking is correct and I don't miss any exits.

Answer (score 0):

The exit event always will be called if your process ends, so I think it will be enough.